# Meaning of ゆとり　in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, definitions

> 浴槽にバラの花びらを浮かべ遊ばせる様な**ゆとり**を

What does ゆとり　in this context mean? My guess is:

> **Time** allowed to play in a bath tub filled with rose petals

According to an online dictionary it should mean time, since it's written in Hiragana. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: I think you should write more context as ゆとり can be interrupted many meaning here. ゆとり means something has enough spare. For instance, ゆとりある生活 means a life with enough spare money. ゆとりあるスケジュール means a schedule with enough spare time. According to what you wrote, I can't make sure what has enough spare. It might be talking about time, maybe money, or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, 「ゆとり」 would mean more like "***mental affluence***" than "time".  It would be synonymous to 「心{こころ}のゆとり」, which we also often use.

One would, of course, certainly need to have time to obtain mental affluence.